# Resolution issue with QTextCursor::insertImage ( const QImage & image, const QString & name = QString() )

Tags: qt, resolution, qimage, qtextcursor

I’d like to insert a QImage inside a QTextDocument and save it as a PDF file.
To do this i use the QTextCursor::insertImage ( const QImage & image, const QString & name = QString() ) method
but the image is pixelized.
With the same image and with the QTextCursor::insertImage ( const QTextImageFormat & format, QTextFrameFormat::Position alignment ) method it is fine.

here is an example:

```
//! Initialise l'imprimante
QPrinter printer;
printer.setOutputFileName(fileDir);
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
printer.setPaperSize(QPrinter::A4);
printer.setPageMargins(20,20,20,20, QPrinter::Millimeter);
printer.setColorMode(QPrinter::Color);
printer.setResolution(300);

//! Initialise le document et le style
//! Document
QTextDocument *doc = new QTextDocument();
doc->setPageSize(printer.paperSize(QPrinter::Millimeter));
doc->setDefaultFont(QFont("Arial", 4));
QTextCursor cursor(doc);


QTextImageFormat picture1;
picture1.setName("./imagename.png");
picture1.setWidth(150);

QImage picture2;
picture2.load("./imagename.png");
picture2 = picture2.scaledToWidth(150);

cursor.insertImage(picture1,QTextFrameFormat::InFlow);
cursor.insertText("\n");
cursor.insertImage(picture2);

doc->print(&printer);
```

Here is a screen capture with the difference between a QTextImageFormat insertion and a QImage insertion in my QTextDocument .
[image: resulting document]
The image does not correspond exactly to the above code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
picture2 = picture2.scaledToWidth(150, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
```

Let me know if it makes any difference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately there is no difference; I scale down the image; does a screen capture may help to find the issue?

Comment: @VincentVilain I looked through the sources, and what `QTextCursor::insertImage(const QImage & image, const QString & name = QString())` does, is it adds a resource to the `QTextDocument` and loads it to a `QTextImageFormat`, and then calls `QTextCursor::insertImage(const QTextImageFormat & format)`. It also seems scaling `QImage` is different from scaling `QTextImageFormat`.